# Validação de has_and_belongs_to_many em Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-record

Tenho os seguintes models:

```
class Pedido < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :produtos
  validate :has_one_or_less_produtos

  private

  def has_one_or_less_produtos
    errors.add(:produtos, 'Não é permitido mais de 1 produto') if produtos.size >= 1
  end
end

class Produto < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :pedidos
end
```

Entretanto ao adicionar mais de um produto no pedido:

`Pedido.first.produtos << Produto.last`

a validação não funciona, qual o problema?

Comment: Por que você está usando :has_and_belongs_to_many se você quer que o pedito tenha no máximo 1 produto?

Comment: Porque depende da regra de negócio, hoje preciso que seja um, mas meu cliente pode solicitar para ser 2 ou mais. Aquele "1" da validação, vamos dizer que seria um parâmetro do sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se a abordagem correta seria many to many pra esse caso, mas já que você está fazendo isso você deve ter uma tabela intermediaria dessa relação, crie um model dela ex.:

```
class PedidosProdutos < ActiveRecord::Base 
  #caso o nome da tabela seja pedidos_produtos poderia ser produtos_pedidos 
  belongs_to :pedido
  belongs_to :produtos
  validates_uniqueness_of :pedido_id
end

class Pedido < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pedidos_produtos
  has_many :produtos, through: :pedidos_produtos

end

class Produto < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pedidos_produtos
  has_many :pedidos, through: :pedidos_produtos
end
```

dessa forma não será adicionado dois produtos pra um mesmo pedido

Answer (score 0):

Ben-Hur,
Sua lógica está quase certa, porém para many to many existe uma forma mais simples de fazer, ao invés de utilizar muitos has_many em várias tabelas,

#### Exemplo

```
class PedidosProdutos < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pedido
  belongs_to :produtos
  validates_uniqueness_of :pedido_id
end

class Pedido < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :produtos, :join_table => :pedidos_produtos
end

class Produto < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :pedidos
end
```